# Lightbox - multiple images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I'm using [bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/jbutz/bootstrap-lightbox) in order to show up certain images in a page.

```html
<a href="#lightbox" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="/img/img1_thumb.png" />
</a>
<a href="#lightbox" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="/img/img2_thumb.png" />
</a>

<div id="lightbox" ...>
  <div class='lightbox-header'>
    <button type="button" class="close" ...>&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class='lightbox-content'>
    <img src="/img/img1.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I simply need to show the full version of the thumbnail that is clicked.

Is there a `lightbox` way to update the `lightbox-content`s `img` before opening the modal ?

Or should I add something like:

```js
$('.thumbnail').click(function () {
    $('#lightbox .lightbox-content img')
        .attr('src', $(this).attr('data-imagefull'));
});
```

?

---

**Update**

I'm not trying to generate the full image path automatically.
I just don't know where to specify this full image path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to look at the source of the plugin. It seems, it has it's own definition for that: https://github.com/jbutz/bootstrap-lightbox/blob/master/js/bootstrap-lightbox.js#L318

You can use the ***'data-image'*** property to make the lightbox update it's contents. Easiest way for you would be probably to write a small script that gets all images with the lightbox ID and set the data-image property to something without the '_thumb' in the filename(e.g. via regex)

Comment: `data-image` is that I was searching for. Is it documented somewhere ? I didn't see. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure wether it is documented, I just looked it up in the source code(I've linked the line - 318. But line 310 also might be of interest).

Comment: It was still present in the [tagged version 0.5.0](https://github.com/jbutz/bootstrap-lightbox/blob/v0.5.0/js/bootstrap-lightbox.js) but seems to have been removed in the current master..

Answer (score 2):

demo :- http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/
you can find your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net yo can do a PageMethod:

js:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function () {

     PageMethods.loadimg(function (answer) {

        var images= answer.split('|');

        $('.lightbox-content').html(answer[0]);
        $('.lightbox-content').html(answer[1]);
        $('.lightbox-content').html(answer[...]);    

    }, Error);
});
```

cs:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string loadimg()
   {
   string images= "<img src="/img/img1_thumb.png" />|<img src="/img/img2_thumb.png" />|<img src="/img/img..._thumb.png" />";
   return images;
   }
```